# Why is Bhangra music often fused with Jamaican/Reggae music?

Tags: genre, reggae

I listen to a lot of bhangra and quite often notice that it fuses with or samples Reggae/Jamaican music for example  or Eh Koka Mere Sajna Da by Holle Holle or Yaar Di Shadi by Bombay Talkie. (Songs can be found in Spotify).

Does anyone know why this is - is there a particularly strong link between British Punjabi and British Jamaican culture?

Comment: Interesting question, have wondered about this myself...

Comment: I suppose these guys grew up listening to **Steel Pulse**, **Black Roots**, **The Specials**, **The Clash**...

Answer (score 2):

The influential 1993 album *No Reservations,* by the British Asian group Apache Indian, first fused Bhangra and raggamuffin-style dancehall reggae, giving birth to the hybrid subgenre known as "Bhangragga."  The two parent styles share an emphasis on dance-driven percussion.

The style remains popular in British Commonwealth countries, where there are large populations of youth of both South Asian and Afro-Caribbean descent living in the same areas and intermingling.  It is relatively unknown elsewhere.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhangragga

Comment: A studio I worked in in the late 80s was recording both genres side by side. The bands would know each other, even though they were from different ethnic & musical backgrounds. They had been to the same schools, grew up together. It's no wonder the styles, like the people, eventually melded.